# Which synamorphy evolved last

Tags: cladistics

I know that if species are on the same height level, they existed at the same time and indicates extinction. Does that apply to synamorphy? Did hair and eggs with shells evolve at the same time or did one evolve last?

[image: here is the cladogram e]

Comment: Your CAPS is on, it reads like you are yelling.

Answer (score 3):

A cladogram does not indicate time. That would be a calibrated phylogram. We can tell from the above cladogram that the two synapomorphies "Hair" and "Eggs" with shells are the two most recent, and happened after all the other ones because cladograms do indicate the relative timing of events. However, knowing a bit about mammals, "Hair" is the more recent than eggs with shells. Actually, eggs with shells should be on the same internode as "Amniotic eggs" in this cladogram, because Montreme mammals had eggs with shells, which were lost in the most recent common ancestor of Marsupials and Eutherians (Primates and Rodents/Rabbits are both Eutherians). So "eggs with shells" came first.

Comment: Thank you very much Karl Kier. Lets say we didn't know which came frst (ignoring your explanation that hair is more recent than egg with shells). Would you be able to tell which came first, hair or eggs with shells, SOLEY, by looking at th cladogram (by comparing their respective heights on the cladogram)?

Comment: No. Cladograms are about relative relationships. So deeper in the tree is older, but by definition, sister groups (in this case Eutherians and Archosaurs) are of equal age. There is no estimate of branch lengths in cladograms. Its just not what they do. There are ways to estimate time with clock methods and models. But cladograms don't do that.

Comment: @KarlKjer I believe they are refeed to calcified eggs which synapids do not have.

Comment: @John Pelicosuars, and many if not all the extinct synapsid mammal-like reptiles (mammal ancestors) likely had calcified eggs, all of which are placed on this internode.

Comment: Do you have a source for that because I have never heard of calcified eggs for Pelycosaurs or synapsids. And that would be a pretty important discovery.

Comment: @John Interesting. I may have fallen prey to something I have always warned others against; assuming that pelycosaurs are like dinosaurs, when clearly they are not. However, it is safe to assume that they laid eggs on land. And turtles, crocs, and dinosaurs laid calcified eggs despite their phylogenetic distance. And Monotremes lay eggs. The cladogram said "eggs with a shell", which monotremes have. Why is calcification a critical part of that definition? I confess to not knowing if monotreme eggs are calcified.

Comment: calcification varies in reptiles, some including monotremes show none, others including turtles crocs and gekko show some calcification with varying degrees of thickness and structure, hard thick calcified eggs are likely unique to dinosaurs and their descendants birds. http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/08912963.2013.829824?src=recsys&journalCode=ghbi20